# Using jQuery, how do I detect which <input type='image> was clicked in a form with multiple submit images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

Let's say we have this form:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="some_name" value="val" id="some_name">
  <input type="image" value="action" alt="Add To Cart" name="add" src="/images/submit.gif">
  <input type="image" value="action" alt="Shop some more" name="return" src="/continue_shopping.gif">
</form>
```

How do I find the input that submitted the form?

Comment: I have tried to serialize the form and examine that data, but the image input form entity wasn't in the form array.

Comment: This question to me is still unanswered though.  The selected answer solves the larger question, but I still don't know how to find out which button was clicked from another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add IDs to your different input items :

```
<input id="SomeName" type="text" name="some_name" value="val" id="some_name">
<input id="AddCart" type="image" value="action" alt="Add To Cart" name="add" src="/images/submit.gif">
<input id="Return" type="image" value="action" alt="Shop some more" name="return" src="/continue_shopping.gif" />
```

And then, in your jQuery, access the events with

```
    $("#Return").click(function(){
    //do your stuff
    });
```

Comment: I'm trying to trigger the action on form submit just in case they don't click on one of the images, but hit [return] out of a text input.  One of the buttons submits the item to the cart, the other lets the customer continue shopping without adding the item.

Comment: This worked great!  Because I didn't have access to the element in the source (CGI tag on my templated store), I just added the id and then bound the click action to the id I previously added.